# Create the login page in Javascript that tells errors while login

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, dom-events

I want to create a login page, in that I want few things that if I enter wrong userid than it will give alert and if left blank then it will give alert and also for inappropriate email address and in the case of password it will show the same.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      function check(form) {
        if (form.userid.value == "id") {
            alert("correct username")
        }
        else if(form.userid.value == "") {
            alert(blank username)
        }

        if (form.pswrd.value == "123") {
            alert("correct details")
        }
        else if(form.pswrd.value == "") {
            alert(blank username)
        }

        else {
            alert("Error Password or Username")
        }
      }
    </script>
     
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Login </h1>
      <form name="login">
          Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
          Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
          <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
          <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a very bad practice to give hints about what is going wrong in a login phase. A malicious user can be sure he knows a username this way. Always give a message of login failed

Comment: And code the password in the javascript would make it easy for anyone to log in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tons of syntax errors in your code, such as `elseif` which is not supported by JavaScript, missing quotes, bad brackets. Are you using a IDE to help you code? In any case you can have a patched version of your code here:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function check(form) {
            if(form.userid.value == "id") {
                alert("correct username")
            } else if (form.userid.value == "") {
                alert ("blank username")
            } else if(form.pswrd.value == "123") {
                alert("correct details")
            } else if(form.pswrd.value == "") {
                alert ("blank password")
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Login </h1>
<form name="login">
    Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
    Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
    <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect on writting `elseif`, it must be have a space, and looks like `else if`. Hope this link help you [JavaScript If...Else Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you should use event **onsubmit** in form open tag instead of **onclick** in submit input tag.
User can submit form by pressing enter.